# Writing up a split function using higher order functions

Tags: ocaml

I've run into an issue trying to write up a function that divides and drops elements based on the function passed through the list.

The function's type should be:

```
'('a -> bool) -> a list -> 'a list list
```

and operate  like `divide_list (fun x -> x mod 3 = 0) [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]`

Which should evaluate to  `[[1; 2]; [4; 5]; [7; 8]; [10]]`.

What I currently have is

```
let divide_list cond lst =
    let f elem (t, f) =
        if cond elem then
        ( elem :: t, f)
        else
        (t, elem ::f)
    in
List.fold_right f lst ([] ,[])
```

and it gives me a type of `('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list`

it doesn't drop the elements inside the list. If anyone could help me with this problem, I would love to know what works.

Comment: Another solution I have which kind of works is this  let divide_list eq lst = List.map (fun x -> if eq x then [] else [x]) lst.

Comment: Your best bet in these kind of problem is to have an auxiliary recursive function that handles one element at a time. I'll answer with a more complete write-up whenever I have some time to do it. :)

Comment: Don't delete the entire body of your question. If your post has been flagged it may be deleted but once you asked something what you wrote is no longer yours and belong to the community and the answers make no sense if you replace your question by "This post has been flagged. Sorry about this".

Answer (score 2):

This part is the core:

```
    if cond elem then
      (elem :: t, f)
    else
      (t, elem ::f)
```

What you do here is assign all the elements for which the condition is true to one list, and all the elements for which it is false to another list. So you're just dividing the list into those that match and those that don't, instead of splitting on and discarding those that match.

So the first thing you should do is not add the elements that match to any list. Instead, I suggest you use the first list as the "current" list you append elements that don't match to, and use the second list to store the "completed" lists. That is, the tuple would have the type `'a list * |a list list` and could be destructured as `(current, completed)`.

When you encounter an element that matches the condition, you then need to append the `current` list to the `completed` lists, and create a new empty `current` list to start appending elements to.

Once the fold is done, you'll also have to append the last `current` list to the `completed` lists (if it's not empty, probably) before returning it.

Hope that helps!

Edit:

Since @Goswin offered up some code, I figured I'd code this up again to see how it compares:

```
let divide_list cond lst =
  let f elem (current, completed) =
    if cond elem then
      ([], current :: completed)
    else
      (elem :: current, completed)
  in let (current, completed) = List.fold_right f lst ([] ,[])
  in current :: completed
```

Using `fold_right` is simpler, closer to your own code, and does not seem to differ noticably in performance for small lists. BUT since `fold_left` is tail-recursive, and `fold_right` is not, it's definitely going to be noticable with very large lists.

[Performance comparison](https://rebench.github.io/?rebench-data=NoIgNgpgLgBAJgSwG4LhA+mBBnK6BOMAvDABQDGA9gHZwA0MYuAlMQHwwDeAOtTI9BgAzYmQiQAtgwoBXfPgjUoDKhIAOkKBDjNWRNr378EIijTilxECbq6Gj-UsAC6DYOTkKlDAHR-VGtDazsz2-AC+MOLYEHZ8DmTAVlIwfj4e8opQrjABmtqh8REA3PaaZBleyrmU6vk6ogAyOFA+QpRgcAQIAOYAFlCkQgxM1U45Lrql8e6eWb7+tYFacM684dO85YgoaJgtmKJmtCMs7HH85aQxPRJZ2Aw3d0p6YTDNuG0dXZBCg2+Oa4QW73R7A55QZgMAAeegMRQSJgq5lIsNYPARCUSH1aCiQQJBLwWPie9wmIQBRki0ViGKxDgJEIeMGA0OJpKUFMxVLolPGbhCvO5ozezGm-BxPjxTkl0o5kPZ4LJhQ2vDV1HKAEN5KJgABGBgAJgYAGYGAAWBgAVgYADYGAB2BgADgYAE4GHqAAzOablEQkaHnIMSShwGAm4gkL3FEB0YCgQ1xkAKZM7VAYLC4AhDBja-DMECuUB65OpuggdN7LN4MC5mD5wvOZtAA)

Comment: I actually don't want a tuple, but instead I woudl like a list of a list. The overall type should be of '('a -> bool) -> a list -> 'a list list

Comment: The tuple actually works really well with the fold. You just have to deconstruct it and append the last list to the others after the fold.

Comment: it wouldn't return the type of 'a list list though. How would this be effecient

Comment: The fold wouldn't, no. That's why you need to assemble the final return value afterwards afterwards. You can drop the tuple and just use an `'a list list` directly in the fold if you want, but then you'd have to deconstruct and reconstruct the accumulator every time you need to add an element to its head.

Comment: Then I wouldn't end up with the type of '('a -> bool) -> a list -> 'a list list

Comment: If you do as I say after the fold it will. The fold will return an `'a list * 'a list list`. If you take the first element of that tuple and append it to the second element (which is an `'a list list` already) you'll have exactly what you need. I'm not guessing here, I've actually tried.

Comment: Your condition returns a bool so you will always just split into the list where cond is true and the where it is false: `let as_list cond args = let (a, b) = divide_list cond args in [a; b]`. It's ineficient to use a list during construction, a tuple (array or hashtbl for more condition choices) is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to fold the list passing an 'a list list of completed segments and an 'a list of the current running segment along. The condition is used to decide when to start a new segment run. Note that I'm collecting the items for the result in reverse and using List.rev to get them in the right order when each part is complete.

```
let divide_list cond lst =
    let (segments, segment) =
        List.fold_left
            (fun (segments, segment) x ->
                if cond x
                then ((List.rev segment)::segments, [])
                else (segments, x::segment))
            ([], [])
            lst
    in
    List.rev ((List.rev segment)::segments)
```

This gives:

```
val divide_list : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list list = <fun>
# divide_list (fun x -> x mod 3 = 0) [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2]; [4; 5]; [7; 8]; [10]]
```